NextJS Build fails on Amplify, SSR
I made a nextjs app, version 14.2.9, typescript, app based routing.
Did npm run build localy and it got built. Able to run locally as well.
When I deployed the app on AWS Amplify, it got built again, ran properly, but after few pushed, the build started failing online. Got different errors, but should not be getting them.
Too long to paste here, so pasting part of it :
                                    Error occurred prerendering page "/privacy-policy". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
                                    TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
                                    at t.useContext (/codebuild/output/src2474594105/src/e-can/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:109363)
                                    at p (/codebuild/output/src2474594105/src/e-can/.next/server/chunks/46.js:11:221729)
                                    at h (/codebuild/output/src2474594105/src/e-can/.next/server/chunks/46.js:11:213631)
                                    at au (/codebuild/output/src2474594105/src/e-can/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10446)
                                    at /codebuild/output/src2474594105/src/e-can/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:15122
                                    at aw (/codebuild/output/src2474594105/src/e-can/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
                                    at a_ (/codebuild/output/src2474594105/src/e-can/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
                                    at ab (/codebuild/output/src2474594105/src/e-can/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
                                    at /codebuild/output/src2474594105/src/e-can/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
                                    at aw (/codebuild/output/src2474594105/src/e-can/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
2024-12-17T20:26:20.237Z [INFO]: ✓ Generating static pages (15/15)
2024-12-17T20:26:20.246Z [WARNING]: 
2024-12-17T20:26:20.246Z [WARNING]: > Export encountered errors on following paths:
                                    /_error: /404
                                    /_error: /500
                                    /_not-found/page: /_not-found
                                    /about-us/page: /about-us
                                    /blogs/page: /blogs
                                    /contact/page: /contact
                                    /delete-account/page: /delete-account
                                    /faq/page: /faq
                                    /maintenance/page: /maintenance
                                    /page: /
                                    /privacy-policy/page: /privacy-policy
                                    /refund-policy/page: /refund-policy
                                    /stores/page: /stores
                                    /terms-and-conditions/page: /terms-and-conditions
2024-12-17T20:26:20.265Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2024-12-17T20:26:20.265Z [INFO]: Please read more about Amplify Hosting's support for SSR frameworks to find if your build failure is related to an unsupported feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/amplify-ssr-framework-support.html. You may also find this troubleshooting guide useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html
2024-12-17T20:26:20.265Z [ERROR]: !!! Error: Command failed with exit code 1
2024-12-17T20:26:20.265Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2024-12-17T20:26:20.265Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed

What is weird that I am still able to build properly locally + even on new amplify app.
I tried commenting the cache part in build settings, but the build still fails!
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
#  cache:
#    paths:
#     - .next/cache/**/*
#      - .npm/**/*


Check your git ignore to see if amplify config files are being ignored and not added to the repo sent to amplify
